# Azure AppInsights is not logging Server Response Time

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

We are using "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.1.0.0" and installed appinsight nugget packages. Already configured application. I could see PAGE VIEW, SERVER REQUEST & FAILED REQUEST. But i dont see any Server Response TIME in Azure portal. If i drill-down, i could see OPERATION NAME. Is there any thing missing.

```
  public void LogTrace(string message, Dictionary<string,string> dict)
    {
         TelemetryClient.TrackTrace(message,dict);
    }

    public void LogHttpRequest(string Name,DateTime CreatedDateTime,TimeSpan Duration,string ResponseCode,bool flag)
    {
        TelemetryClient.TrackRequest(Name, CreatedDateTime, Duration, ResponseCode, flag);           
    }

private void LogMessage(string message, SeverityLevel traceSeverity, string title)
    {
       TelemetryClient.TrackTrace(title, traceSeverity, null);
    } 



public void LogMetrics(string PageName, double totalDuration)
    {
   TelemetryClient.TrackMetric(new MetricTelemetry(PageName, totalDuration));
    }

 public void LogCustomEvent(string message, Dictionary<string, string> extendedInformation, Dictionary<string, double> metrics)
    {
        TelemetryClient.TrackEvent(message, extendedInformation, metrics);
    }

public void LogException(Exception ex, string APPNAME)
    {
        var additonal = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        additonal.Add(APPNAME,APPNAME );
        TelemetryClient.TrackException(ex, new Dictionary<string, string>()
           {
                { "Exception Message", ex.Message },
                { "Exception Source", ex.Source },
                { "CallStack",ex.StackTrace??String.Empty}
           }, new Dictionary<string, double>()
            {
                { "Total HTTP Exceptions", 1 }
            });         
    }
```

Is there any thing which I'm missing, that reason we couldn't see any server response time.

Comment: What type of application and service are you running? PAAS web sites? IIS site on VMs? Hosted APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, I assumed that you are using Application Insights API for custom metrics. I checked [TrackRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#trackrequest) and used the following code for logging HTTP request as follows:

```
TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient()
{
    InstrumentationKey = "{your-Instrumentation-Key}"
};
client.TrackRequest(new RequestTelemetry()
{
    Name = "/api/values",
    StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
    ResponseCode = "200",
    Success = true
});
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

[image]

In summary, please make sure your event type is correct and could contain the duration.